# Custom setting at un-install for file/folder deletion

Tags: windows, installation, advanced-installer

Using [Advanced installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html) for my java based application, it is working very good. I want to **remove one folder and one file when user uninstall the application from system**. Now my question is

1) how to remove a file from a given location e-g i have an `abc` file at desktop and i want if it exist there it should be deleted while user will uninstall the application(file will be on the same path and with same name for all) ?

2) how to delete a folder from the system while user uninstalling the application ?

3) if (2 i-e folder deletion) is possible then, can i change the location of the folder(i want to delete at uninstall) programmatic-ally ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly share you experiences in this regard,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your are using the latest version of Advanced Installer.

1) You can go to Files and Folders page and from the toolbar, under ["File Operations"](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/file-operations.html), add a File Removal, which you can configure to run during install or uninstall

2) Right click on the desired folder and go to ["Operations" tab](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/folder-removal-dialog.html), there you will find the options you need

3) Yes, you can specify the path programmatic-ally, but you need to do it from the beginning of the install process, using a property based folder. So basically you [create your property based folder](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-custom-folder.html) and configure options from Operations tab for it.